# Можно ли асинхронный сокет ставить одновременно на чтение и запись?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, сокет

У меня многопоточное приложение, которое принимает соединения от клиентов по tcp. Я использую асинхронную модель через IoCompletionPort и wsa***.

**Можно ли асинхронный сокет ставить одновременно на чтение и запись?**

Когда я в отладчике последовательно проверяю каждый обмен с клиентом, то все чики-пики. А когда отпускаю отладчик, то WSA_OPERATION_ABORTED. Хоть тресни. По своей сути я проксирую трафик от клиента к другому процессу, потому что он зашифрован, процесс не может расшифровать (нет делегирования TLS между процессами). Короче клиент шлет всякую муть, сервер расшифровывает и шлет процессу, который уже обработает. Один поток вычитывает сокет клиента и пишет в сокет процесса, а другой поток вычитывает сокет процесса и пишет в сокет клиента. Т.к. это tcp, то сокет у клиента один на обе операции, как и у процесса.